# Why does Responsive FileManager resize images after upload?

Tags: upload, file-manager, responsive-filemanager

I am using Responsive FileManager to upload images to my site. However, there is a problem that whenever I upload an image its immediately resized and cropped to a smaller size. Does anyone know why is this happening and is there a way to stop it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the `config.php` file and set `$image_resizing` to `false`:

```
//Automatic resizing //
    // If you set $image_resizing to TRUE the script converts all uploaded images exactly to image_resizing_width x image_resizing_height dimension
    // If you set width or height to 0 the script automatically calculates the other dimension
    // Is possible that if you upload very big images the script not work to overcome this increase the php configuration of memory and time limit
    'image_resizing'                          => false,
    'image_resizing_width'                    => 0,
    'image_resizing_height'                   => 0,
    'image_resizing_mode'                     => 'auto', // same as $image_max_mode
    'image_resizing_override'                 => false,
    // If set to TRUE then you can specify bigger images than $image_max_width & height otherwise if image_resizing is
    // bigger than $image_max_width or height then it will be converted to those values
```